# How to create a truly static variable with CMAKE compilation?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation

In the following macro:

```
#define REGISTER_CLASS(CLASSNAME) struct CLASSNAME; \
    static bool CLASSNAME##registered = \
    (\
        (Register<CLASSNAME>()), \
        true \
    );
```

The class is registered correctly with the register function if used before a class. However, if we have inheritance such as:

```
REGISTER_CLASS(Foo)
class Foo
{
    // ...
};

// Another file:

REGISTER_CLASS(FooBar1)
class FooBar1: public Foo 
{
    // ...
};

// Another file:

REGISTER_CLASS(FooBar2)
class FooBar2: public Foo 
{
    // ...
};
```

The Foo class is registered multiple times, despite `Fooregistered` being a static variable. Now, what makes this weird, is that when I compile this code without cmake, we get correct behavior:

https://onlinegdb.com/WsxMOrncf

Comment: Why do you think that `Foo` is registered more than once?  Only one line of the code explicitly uses it.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's a great question. For some reason, it just does that when compiled with CMAKE and I can't figure it out

Comment: Class definitions are usually in header files. Since header content is copied every time it is `#include`d, every translation unit is going to have own copy of that variable (and initialise it on its own).

Comment: Make this variable `inline` instead of `static` to merge the copies of the variable from different TUs. But also check for duplicate registrations in `Register<T>()`, because `inline` merging won't work across dll boundaries if you add them.

Comment: If you think that CMake is related to the problem, then most likely you need to add your `CMakeLists.txt` to the question post. Otherwise I see no reason to note CMake in the title and in the question body.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I believe reading through the post, you can sere how it's related to CMAKE.

Comment: CMake just calls the compiler with arguments deduced from your `CMakeLists.txt`. The only specifics of CMake is that in case of executable consisting from **several sources**, every source is compiled separately into its own object file, and then the object files are linked together. (When one directly invokes the compiler, he/she usually passes all sources files to it). But your onlinegdb link contains only single source file - `main.cpp`, so that specifics of CMake is not applied. So no, without viewing `CMakeLists.txt` I don't see how the problem is related to CMake.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `Fooregistered` variable must be inline to merge the copies of the variable across translation units.